# SpEL #{#entityName} alternative in Spring Data JDBC

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jdbc

I am extending a base repository with shared queries across entities but unfortunately spring does not support derived [delete](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-relational/issues/771) queries in spring data jdbc.

I had to write a custom query in all my repositories:

```
@Modifying
@Query("DELETE FROM table WHERE user=:user AND id=:id")
void deleteByUserAndId(@Param("user") int user, @Param("id") Integer id);
```

Is there a way to get spring to map the entity name into the query like `#{#entityName}`  found [here.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/1.7.x/reference/html/)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is currently no such feature. I also don't think there exists a feature request for this. Feel free to create a ticket asking for it.